# Implode column values

Tags: php

I want to have one array from these two tags so I can reference it through my client using either tag from the index

```
$query = "SELECT username,imgDefault from users"
$result = $sql->query($query);
$rows = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {               
            $rows[]=$row;
        }
        $result->close();
        $sql->close();
$str = implode(',', array_map(function($el){ return $el['username']; }, $rows));
$str1 = implode(',', array_map(function($el){ return $el['imgDefault']; }, $rows));
```

Desired Output Array

```
username:"d" imgDefault: "a", username:"b" imgDefault: "q",  etc....
```

I'm open to any other output that would help me identify the column value on an index.

Comment: dont delete(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529216/php-implode-multiple-tags-in-same-array) and repost - its very rude

Comment: im not sure what you are asking. can you show the "final result" you are trying to achieve? That is to say, show how the array you are trying to get would be structured

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't have any idea what this question is asking!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you're trying to do is to have the possibility to get a "username" based on a "imgDefault" OR to get a "imgDefault" based on a "username".

You should first get an associative array where the key is the username, and the value is the imgDefault:
    $query = "SELECT username,imgDefault from users"
    $result = $sql->query($query);

```
$associativeArray = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {               
    $currUsername = $row["username"];
    $currImgDefault = $row["imgDefault"];
    $associativeArray[$currUsername]= $currImgDefault;
}
$result->close();
$sql->close();
// $array will look like array("d" => "a", "b" => "q", ...);
```

Then you can look for a "imgDefault" based on a "username" using:

```
if (array_key_exists($theUsername, $associativeArray))
{
    $theImgDefault = $associativeArray[$theUsername];
}
```

And you can look for a "username" based on a "imgDefault" using:

```
$theUsername = array_search($theImgDefault,$associativeArray);
```